# Convert MongoDB bson.int64.Int64 back to a long number (and a datetime)

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, bson

Data in MongoDB is stored like this, it should have probably been an ISODate but it wasn't:

```
"timestamp": {
    "$numberLong": "1599142085021078272"
},
```

In Python 3, I retrieve data and do this:

```
testDateTimeStamp = doc['timestamp']
print ("testDateTimeStamp:", testDateTimeStamp, " type=", type(testDateTimeStamp))
rowDateTime = datetime1.datetime.fromtimestamp(testDateTimeStamp)
```

The print command seems to untangle it, and shows this, but how do I convert it back to a datetime in my code?

```
testDateTimeStamp: 1599152715643496874  type= <class 'bson.int64.Int64'>
```

then it gets an error:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: 1599142085021078272 this to a date or time?

Comment: It's a time, with a lot of precision.

Comment: You can paste it here: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: wow , this is nice ! good to know this info

Answer (score 0):

This is my first attempt to get it working.  If there is a better way please let me know.  I did remember that earlier I had to divide to get rid of the nanoseconds.

```
one_minute = datetime1.timedelta(minutes=1)
testDateTimeStamp = int(int(doc['timestamp']) / 1000000000)
print ("testDateTimeStamp:", testDateTimeStamp, " type=", type(testDateTimeStamp))
rowDateTime = datetime1.datetime.fromtimestamp(testDateTimeStamp)
```